# ¿Cómo organizar mis datos en un nuevo array?

Tags: php, sql

Tengo que hacer unas tarjetas en las que muestro información del usuario junto con la información de las paradas que hace ese día.

La consulta la ejecuto de manera correcta y listo los resultados de esta manera:

```
AÑO  DIA SEMANA HORA  NOMBRE           TELEFONO  PARADA
==== ========== ====  ================ ========= ==========
2017 1          855   APE1 APE2,NOMBRE 123456789 PARADA BUS 
2017 1          1040  APE1 APE2,NOMBRE 123456789 PARADA BUS2 
2017 2          855   APE1 APE2,NOMBRE 123456789 PARADA BUS 
2017 2          1040  APE1 APE2,NOMBRE 123456789 PARADA BUS2 
2017 3          855   APE1 APE2,NOMBRE 123456789 PARADA BUS 
2017 3          1040  APE1 APE2,NOMBRE 123456789 PARADA BUS2 
2017 3          1530  APE1 APE2,NOMBRE 123456789 PARADA BUS3 
2017 4          855   APE1 APE2,NOMBRE 123456789 PARADA BUS 
2017 4          1150  APE1 APE2,NOMBRE 123456789 PARADA BUS3
```

Y si tengo que organizar la información en el `html` de la siguiente forma:

```
AÑO : 2017
DIA SEMANA: 1
NOMBRE: APE1 APE2, NOMBRE
TELEFONO: 123456789
PARADAS:
    HORA: 855
    LUGAR: PARADA BUS
    HORA: 1040
    LUGAR: PARADA BUS2
AÑO : 2017
DIA SEMANA: 2
NOMBRE: APE1 APE2, NOMBRE
TELEFONO: 123456789
PARADAS:
    HORA: 855
    LUGAR: PARADA BUS
    HORA: 1040
    LUGAR: PARADA BUS2
...
```

no tendría problemas.

Pero en este caso si las paradas y su hora coinciden tengo que agruparlos en una misma tarjeta, de esta manera

```
AÑO : 2017
DIA SEMANA: 1-2
NOMBRE: APE1 APE2, NOMBRE
TELEFONO: 123456789
PARADAS:
    HORA: 855
    LUGAR: PARADA BUS
    HORA: 1040
    LUGAR: PARADA BUS2
```

Los resultados los cojo en un array multidimensional de php y se pueden leer de esta forma:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($resultado);$i++){
    echo $resultado[$i][/*NOMBRE DEL CAMPO*/]
}
```

### EDICIÓN

Por ahora he conseguido, mostrar si el grupo de paradas y horas de un día es igual o no al del día anterior, lo he hecho de la siguiente manera:

```
function creaGrupo($resultado){
    $diaAnterior = 0;
    $grupoValor = "";
    $grupo=array();;
    for($i=0;$i<count($resultado);$i++){            
        if($i==0){
            $diaAnterior = $resultado[$i]["DIASEMANA"];
            $grupoValor = $resultado[$i]["HORA"].$resultado[$i]["PARADA"]."|";
        }else{
            if($resultado[$i]["DIASEMANA"]==$diaAnterior){
                $grupoValor = $resultado[$i]["HORA"].$resultado[$i]["PARADA"]."|";
            }else{
                array_push($grupo,$grupoValor);             
                $grupoValor = "";
                $grupoValor = $resultado[$i]["HORA"].$resultado[$i]["PARADA"]."|";
            }
            $diaAnterior = $resultado[$i]["DIASEMANA"];
        }                                       
    }   
    array_push($grupo,$grupoValor); 
    return $grupo;
}       
$grupo = creaGrupo($resultado);
for($i=0;$i<count($grupo);$i++){
        echo $grupo[$i]."<br/>";
        if($i != 0){
            if ($grupo[$i] == $grupo[$i-1]){
                echo "El grupo ".($i-1)."y ".$i."son iguales<br/>";
            }else{
                echo "El grupo ".($i-1)."y ".$i."no son iguales<br/>";
            }
        }
}
```

De esta manera muestro por pantalla que días tienen las paradas iguales, ahora solo queda listar...

**NOTA**: Se que el titulo de la pregunta no es el mejor del mundo (se ve que hoy no es mi mejor día). Si se os ocurre uno mejor cambiarlo.

Comment: sin codigo va a ser dificil ayudarte... a que te referis con que no funcionaba nada.. en php o sql?

Comment: @gbianchi en php, cuando me refiero a que no funcionaba nada es que era incapaz de que cuando las paradas y la hora son iguales a las paradas y la hora del día anterior mostrarlo en un solo bloque como el que he mostrado. Como digo en la pregunta, el problema no es la consulta si no mostrar los datos de manera correcta en PHP. Y lo de que sin código no me puedes ayudar, no entiendo muy bien porque, doy los datos y la manera de acceder a ellos, solo hay que realizar operaciones lógicas para mostrar el resultado de manera correcta, el problema es que no encuentro la forma de que esto ocurra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de un largo y tedioso proceso he conseguido hacerlo, supongo que no sera la mejor manera de hacerlo, pero funciona.

```
$paradasPorDia = "";
$arrParadasPorDia = Array();
$resultadoFinal ="";
$arrResultadoFinal = Array();
//En el primer for agrupo las paradas que tiene un dia
for($i=0;$i<count($resultado);$i++){
    $paradasPorDia = $resultado[$i]["USUARIO"]."-"; 
    $resultado2 = listado2($resultado[$i]["DIASEMANA"]);
    for($j=0;$j<count($resultado2);$j++){
        if($j==0){
            $paradasPorDia = $paradasPorDia.$resultado2[$j]["HORA"]."~".$resultado2[$j]["PARADA"];          
        }else{
            $paradasPorDia = $paradasPorDia."|".$resultado2[$j]["HORA"]."~".$resultado2[$j]["PARADA"];      
        }       
    }
    array_push($arrParadasPorDia,$paradasPorDia);       
}
//En el Segundo for adjunto las paradas que tiene un dia al usuario y muestro con que dias es igual
for($i=0;$i<count($resultado);$i++){    
    $paradaHoy = $arrParadasPorDia[($resultado[$i]["DIASEMANA"])-1];    
    $resultadoFinal = $resultado[$i]["ANO"]."-".$resultado[$i]["TELEFONO"]."-".$paradaHoy."-";
    for($j=0;$j<count($arrParadasPorDia);$j++){     
        if($paradaHoy == $arrParadasPorDia[$j]){            
            $resultadoFinal = $resultadoFinal. ($j+1) .",";
        }       
    }   
    $resultadoFinal = trim($resultadoFinal,",");
    array_push($arrResultadoFinal,$resultadoFinal); 
}
//Elimino los equivalentes
$arrResultadoFinal = array_unique($arrResultadoFinal);

//echo $arrResultadoFinal[0]."<br/>";

//Muestro el resultado
foreach($arrResultadoFinal as $resultado){
    echo "TARJETA<br/>";
    $valores = explode("-",$resultado);         
    for($a = 0;$a < count($valores);$a++){
        if($a == 4){
            echo "Dia semana: ".$valores[$a]."</br>";   
        }
        if($a == 0){
            echo "AÑO: ". $valores[$a]."</br>"; 
        }
        if($a == 1){
            echo "TELEFONO: ". $valores[$a]."</br>";    
        }
        if($a == 2){
            echo "USUARIO: ". $valores[$a]."</br>"; 
        }
        if($a == 3){
            $paradas = explode("|",$valores[$a]);
            for($b = 0;$b < count($paradas);$b++){
                $valoresParadas = explode("~",$paradas[$b]);
                for($c = 0; $c < count($valoresParadas);$c++){
                    if($c==0){
                        echo "Hora : ".$valoresParadas[$c]."</br>"; 
                    }
                    if($c==1){
                        echo "Parada : ".$valoresParadas[$c]."</br>";   
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<hr/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sugerencia para el título: **¿Cómo organizar mis datos en un nuevo array?**

Hola Andoni, no es necesario complicarte mucho.

Usas lo que necesitas que coincida como llave del array, dicho de otra forma, los datos que usas una vez por tarjeta. Los separas con algún separador. Lo demás puedes hacerlo otra dimensión del mismo array.

```
while($resultado = $mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ){
  $array[$resultado['hora'] . '_' . $resultado['año'] . '_' . $resultado['parada']][] = $resultado['nombre'];
}
```

Después recorres el array para crear una tarjeta por llave:

```
foreach($array as $llave => $valor){
  $datos_fijos = explode('_', $llave);
  echo "Año: $datos_fijos[1] <br /> Parada: $datos_fijos[2] <br /> Hora: $datos_fijos[0] <br /> Nombres: " . implode(',', $valor) . "<hr>";

}
```

En este ejemplo el resultado de un query imaginario sería:

```
Año: 2017
Parada: Parada 1
Hora: 3090
Nombres: Raúl,Pedro, Salomón.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Año: 2017
Parada: Parada 2
Hora: 3060
Nombres: Pedro, Salomón, María
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que hace tu código, quiero decir, en el while recorres el resultado uno a uno por lo que lo guardas por lineas como si yo hiciera `echo $resultado["hora"].$resultado....` lo que me deja mosca es lo que haces `$resultado['parada']][] = $resultado['nombre']` ¿Qué hace es parte del código exactamente?

Comment: Está creando `$array['1033_2017_PARADA1']['Alejandro', 'Raul', 'Pedro'];` luego hay una implosión cuando imprimes las tarjetas. Podrías hacer `$array[$resultado['hora'] . '_' . $resultado['año'] . '_' . $resultado['parada']]['nombres'][] = $resultado['nombre'];` y una segunda línea para teléfonos y luego implotar $valor['nombres'] y $valor['telefonos'].

Comment: Pero entonces los datos no se estan mostrando como yo deseo, aqui estas mostrando los nombres de las personas con las mismas paradas, yo quiero mostrar las paradas por dias de la semana, y si, por ejemplo el dia 1, 2 , 3 tiene las mismas paradas, poner en una misma tarjeta. A cada usuario se le entrega una tarjeta por dia de la semana pero si por ejemplo estos 3 dias son iguales se le entregaria 3 tarjetas, una para los dias 1,2,3 otra para el 4 y otra para el 5. No tiene mucho sentido crear un tarjeta para 3 personas, ya que cada tarjeta es personal.

Comment: Entiendo pero cambia la forma de ver las cosas... yo estoy ejemplificando una forma correcta de hacerlo, tu tienes que ordenar los datos que vas a usar 1 vez por tarjeta para que sean (todos juntos) la llave del array. Los datos que se pueden repetir por tarjeta (como los nombres) los pones en un array dentro de esa llave o un array dentro del array de esa llave si son varios "tipos" de datos por tarjeta.

Comment: Si eso lo entiendo, pero la cosa es que aunque me pongas un ejemplo, yo no voy a saber tirar bien de ahi, porque no solo tengo que aplicar tu ejemplo a mis datos, lo tengo que hacer en un lenguaje que apenas conozco, por eso yo lo organizo de otra forma, pero mi intención es la misma. Usar las llaves con sus datos, incluso me planteaba usar un `array map` pero al final siempre se me acaban complicando las cosas. Por eso he pedido ayuda para que alguien me muestre una solución directa

Comment: Voy a probar de tu forma pero aun asi habria que agrupar dos veces los arrays, una por paradas que tiene un usuario y otra por paradas iguales que tiene ese usuario durante la semana.

Comment: Entonces me parece que estás concibiendo erróneamente este sitio, que bueno que pudiste resolverlo.

Comment: ¿Por qué estoy concibiendo una erróneamente de este sitio?Acaso el sitio no esta para resolver dudas tanto de errores como de problemas lógicos? Es un sitio para preguntas sobre programación, nose porque dices que estoy equivocado con la idea de este sitio...

Comment: Porque una cosa es resolver dudas de programación y otra diferente es programar por ti. Relacionado a tu código te he proporcionado un ejemplo mínimo y verificable que puedes adaptar a tus necesidades pero me pides que haga la programación que necesitas. Ahí la erronea concepción del sitio. De igual forma, me da gusto que pudieras resolverlo de otra forma.

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por aclararmelo, normalmente no suele ser asi lo que pido pero en este caso lo necesitaba de esta forma.